# How to set custom enumii labels that cycle across items

Tags: enumerate, enumitem

I want to have something that looks like this:

```
1.
  A.
  B.
  C.
  D.
2.
  F.
  G.
  H.
  J.
3.
  A.
  B.
  C.
  D.
```

And it keeps on cycling. Notice that the letters are sometimes not consecutive.

So far I have

```
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\textbf{\Alph{enumii}.}}

\begin{enumerate}
\item
\begin{enumerate}
\item foo
\item foo
\item foo
\item foo
\end{enumerate}
\item
\begin{enumerate}
\item foo
\item foo
\item foo
\item foo
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
```

But obviously this just cycles through A, B, C, and D over and over.

Comment: What determines whether the second-level items are numbered as A, B, C, and D vs. as opposed to F, G, H, and J? What determines which letters (e.g., E and I in your example) are skipped? What determines when the letters should restart (at A, presumably)? Are there always four second-level items below any first-level item?

Comment: It always starts at A. There are always four second-level items. It will always go A,B,C,D,F,G,H,J and then repeat.

Answer (score 5):

Define a new counter representation that uses the counter's value modulo 8. The easiest way to do it is with `expl3`. Then with `enumitem` define a suitable list.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,xparse}

\newlist{nelson}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[nelson,1]{label=\nelsonalph*.,resume}
\AddEnumerateCounter{\nelsonalph}{\donelsonalph}{D}
\newcommand{\nelsonalph}[1]{\expandafter\donelsonalph\csname c@#1\endcsname}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \donelsonalph #1
 {
  \int_case:nn { \int_mod:nn { #1 } { 8 } }
   {
    {0}{J}
    {1}{A}
    {2}{B}
    {3}{C}
    {4}{D}
    {5}{E}
    {6}{F}
    {7}{G}
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item
\begin{nelson}
\item foo
\item foo
\item foo
\item foo
\end{nelson}
\item
\begin{nelson}
\item foo
\item foo
\item foo
\item foo
\end{nelson}
\item
\begin{nelson}
\item foo
\item foo
\item foo
\item foo
\end{nelson}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use `series` facility of `enumitem`

```
\documentclass{Article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item
\begin{enumerate}[label=\Alph*.,series=myseries]
\item foo
\item foo
\item foo
\item foo
\end{enumerate}
\item
\begin{enumerate}[resume*=myseries,start=6]    %% start at F.
\item foo
\item foo
\item foo
\item foo
\end{enumerate}
\item
\begin{enumerate}[resume*=myseries,start=1]    %% start at A. again
\item foo
\item foo
\item foo
\item foo
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If they are random, then use `\item[J.]`, for example.

Comment: how is myseries defined?

Comment: @Nelson In the first `enumerate` like `,series=myseries`. For details, please see `enumitem` documentation, section 3.5, page 6.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an option using [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) and your own counter:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcounter{cycleenum}
\newcommand{\cyclealph}[1]{%
  \ifcase\value{#1}% 0
  \or A% 1
  \or B% 2
  \or C% 3
  \or D% 4
  \or F% 5
  \or G% 6
  \or H% 7
  \or J% 8
  \or \setcounter{#1}{1}\cyclealph{#1}%
  \fi}
\newcommand{\cycleitem}{\refstepcounter{cycleenum}\item[\textbf{\cyclealph{cycleenum}.}]}
\begin{document}


\begin{enumerate}
  \item
  \begin{enumerate}[series=cyclealph]
    \cycleitem foo
    \cycleitem foo
    \cycleitem foo
    \cycleitem foo
    \cycleitem foo
    \cycleitem foo
    \cycleitem foo
    \cycleitem foo
    \cycleitem foo
    \cycleitem foo
    \cycleitem foo
    \cycleitem foo
  \end{enumerate}

  \item
  \begin{enumerate}[resume,series=cyclealph]
    \cycleitem foo
    \cycleitem foo
    \cycleitem foo
    \cycleitem foo
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```